# Opening QGIS or .gqz project files on mac

Tags: qgis, mac, save, qgz

I have an old Macbook pro with QGIS 3.10 installed. I have not been able to open any QGIS projects I have saved because of this error -> ***There is no application set to open the document “test project save.qgz”.***

I was thinking this was most likely a problem of where I had QGIS installed on my computer. I checked and it is under Macintosh HD -> Applications. I have another Applications folder if I go to my user profile from Mac HD which does not seem to have QGIS or R or several other of my apps I regularly use. Instead that folder has many games I play. I am the only user of my computer and so there is only my profile and the default guest one which is empty.

I dont think that QGIS being in the base applications folder for all users should be problematic. That being said, I have no idea why I am getting this error when trying to open my saved QGIS projects. I have used QGIS quite a bit for school and personal interest. I never had a problem when opening saved QGIS projects on school computers other then them being so slow. I have been getting by with just saving layers which is annoying because it doesn't save the properties of layers either.

Can you help, either with being able to save properties of layers on saved layers, or with troubleshooting my issue of opening saved projects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't seem to be the only person with this kind of problem, seems to be a bug:
https://github.com/qgis/QGIS-Mac-Packager/issues/31

There you find some workarounds as well. One workaround however works for you, opening the project file from the QGIS window. Again, saving your projects as qgs instead of qgz should be another solution.